# Will background apps run during screensaver?

Tags: vmware, virtualbox, screensaver

Perhaps I am rendering an image VIA Blender, or what is happening at the time of writing this post, creating a VM. If I put my Mac to screensaver, will background apps continue to run? Like would Virtual Box continue to work in the background, and would blender continue to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The only caveat is that some screensavers consume enough CPU to slightly slow down a job/process using all CPU cores.